# How to open all modified files in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut

The goal is simple - I want to open all modified files at once. Is there a fast way to do it?

Currently I am using  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> and then open files, but that is not fast enough (press shortcut, select all, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, manually open files that are "unversioned")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a **macro** for the keystrokes you mentioned, and assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

1. `Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording`
2. Perform the keystrokes: `ALT+9`, `CTRL+A`, `ENTER`, `ALT+9`
3. `Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording`, give it a name
4. `Settings | Keymap | Macros`, add keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Note on Mac this cmd+9 instead of alt+9.